# Can I create an outlet from patio light but always powered on

Tags: receptacle, outdoor

I am trying to provide an main source for security system. I don't have any socket outside but I do have lights. Could it be possible to construct an outlet or drive a main from this lights so that I can power security system. I am thinking of enclosing this outlet/main wires in some kind of casing to prevent it from rain. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of where'd you like to add the outlet, the inside of that box and the inside of the switch box that controls the outside lights?

Comment: It depends on how it's wired. Please provide more information.

Comment: Please, **turn off the power to the outside lights at the circuit breaker** _then_ take the covers off of the switch and outlets to remove the fixtures and take pictures of the wiring. _Do NOT_ disconnect any of the wiring, just pull the devices out of the box to take clear, focused pictures of the existing wiring connections. Then carefully pack everything back into the boxes, tighten the devices back to their mounts, replace any covers, then turn the breaker back on

Comment: Most security-related devices use low voltage cables that are run in conduit or otherwise inaccessible to bad guys, to an indoor location where they can be connected to a power source.   Can you tell us what exactly you want to install outside and what kind of power source it needs?  It's hard to think of a security device that just plugs into an outdoor AC outlet.  You say "system".  Usually a "system" would have an indoor part with low voltage wires to outdoor gadgets.  Tell us more.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you only have a switched hot at the light location. You'd be able to eliminate the switch and splice the the wires so the lights would always be on and then install a photocell or timer at the first light location to control them. If your electrical system is in conduit, you'd be able to add a wire from your switch to your box location that would give you an always hot. If your system is NB cable from your switch to the light box, you could replace the run with a 12/3 cable so you'd have a switched hot and an always hot. Yes, you would need waterproof boxes.

Comment: Yeah that is possible...I was also thinking of putting an adapter that can convert an bulb holder into bulb holder and socket. But the problem with this approach is that socket is controlled by switch. Are there any adapters that can switch off/on current to light bulb via switch but always hot to socket. Could this be converted for purpose of keeping it on by somehow removing/modifying pull chain:https://www.amazon.com/GE-Adapter-Polarized-Workshop-54180/dp/B002DN2OIS/ref=sr_1_7?dchild=1&keywords=Light+Socket+to+Plug+Adapter+with+with+switch&qid=1600799455&sr=8-7

Comment: This type of adapter has it's outlets always on and the light switches on and off by the chain.... but you need an always hot at the  main socket. Plus these adapters are not rated for outside use.